# How to reset password in Parse Server getting An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset functionality

Tags: php, parse-platform, password-recovery

I am using this below code and i am getting

**An appName, publicServerURL, and emailAdapter are required for password reset functionality.**

Using Code:

```
try {
          ParseUser::requestPasswordReset($data['user_email']);
            // Password reset request was sent successfully
          echo "1";
          exit;
        } catch (ParseException $ex) {
          // Password reset failed, check the exception message
            return array("error" => 1, "success" => 0, 'message' => $ex->getMessage());
                exit;
        }
```

Comment: Do you have the code of the class ParseUser, without it i doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: Yes, I have already done user login. But parse-server not allowing to make direct changes with password.

Comment: Have found a solution for this, I am getting this error in bitnami parse platform when I am trying to reset user password.